# Query timeout is not working in JDBC request

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I have a JDBC request where i fixed the Query timeout as 30 seconds. But most of the times it goes endlessly. Please take a look at below screenshot and let me know if any changes required. I added a duration assertion as well, but it never getting executed.

Query type - Select statement

[image]

[image]

Are there any workarounds available to break the wait after 30 seconds?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

It might be the case of the underlying JDBC driver, i.e. looking into [Different JDBC Query Timeout behaviour in Thin and OCI Driver](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9541594200346889263)

> I can confirm that the query timeout is working with the 18.3 and the 19.3 driver via the Thin driver, if the client is running on a Linux system.
> However, if the client runs on a Windows 7 system the query timeout has no effect when using the Thin driver. **It is only functioning properly with the OCI driver on Windows.**

So if you're running Windows you can consider switching to [JDBC OCI driver](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/instclnt.htm#JJDBC28217) instead of thin.

Duration Assertion will not have any effect as it will only mark the sampler as failed when the sampler ends. And if the sampler "goes endlessly" the assertion won't have any effect as it won't terminate the sampler.

If you cannot switch to OCI driver you could consider using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead of JDBC Request and setting the maximum execution time via [Sample Timeout PreProcessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/quick-guide-jmeter-preprocessors#sample) (it might leave the connection open though)